# Merge File Algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, file, windows-services, .net-2.0

I am writing a Windows service which poll on a specific folder.
The directory contains various files, and each file derives from a previous split operation:

Input folder:

- **FILE_A_PART_1_OF_2.txt**
- **FILE_A_PART_2_OF_2.txt**
- FILE_B_PART_1_OF_3.txt
- FILE_B_PART_2_OF_3.txt
- FILE_C_PART_2_OF_3.txt
- FILE_C_PART_3_OF_3.txt
- FILE_D_PART_1_OF_3.txt
- FILE_D_PART_3_OF_3.txt
- **FILE_E_PART_1_OF_1.txt**

The Services should be able to merge only the complete files:

Output Folder (after the merge operation):

- **FILE_A.txt**
- **FILE_E.txt**

Input Folder (after the merge operation)

- FILE_B_PART_1_OF_3.txt
- FILE_B_PART_2_OF_3.txt
- FILE_C_PART_2_OF_3.txt
- FILE_C_PART_3_OF_3.txt
- FILE_D_PART_1_OF_3.txt
- FILE_D_PART_3_OF_3.txt

Unfortunately i have to use framework 2.0. Language is C#. I know it's not a complicated algorithm but somehow i can't put myself into the right direction.
The merge operation is not important, so it can be expressed like:

`Merge(string[] filesPart)` or `Merge(List<string> filesPart)`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, grab all files, with  `Directory.GetFiles()`

And then your main tool would be the `Dictionary<>` class.
I think I would use something like:

```
class BaseFile
{   
   public int Total { ... }     
   public List<string> Parts { ... }
}    

List<string, BaseFile> baseFiles = ...;
```

This would allow you to scan the list of files, parse the name and store it.
After the scan, only process a file when `Total == Parts.Count`.

As long as the `n`  in  `PART_n_OF_m` remains < 10 you can simply sort the `List<string> Parts`.
When it can become >= 10 you'll need something like `SortedList<int, string> Parts`

Answer (score 2):

To get you started: Given the list of input files, group them by expected output file. Then, for each group, figure out how many files you're expecting. Then, for each group, check to see if you have all of the parts. If you have all of the parts, catenate the files in that group together.